# Batch script to toggle the registry settings

Tags: windows-registry

How to create a batch to toggle between two registry settings. The code which I want to toggle is listed. If the DWORD value is 2 then change it to 0 and vice vera. Any help would be appreciated.

```
@echo off

REM ByPass Login Password Setting
Echo ByPass Login Password 
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PasswordLess\Device /v 
DevicePasswordLessBuildVersion /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
echo %errorlevel%



REM Restore Default Setting
Echo Restore Default Login
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PasswordLess\Device /v 
DevicePasswordLessBuildVersion /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f
echo %errorlevel%


Pause
psshutdown /r /t 0
```

---

Mine modified code but it does not work.

```
@echo off
for /F "skip=2 tokens=2*" %%A in ('reg query 
"HKLM\Software\microsoft\windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /v 
"EnableLUA"') DO (Echo %%B)

If %%B==0x0 (
reg add HKLM\Software\microsoft\windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v 
EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /D 1 /f
echo 1 %errorlevel%
) else (
reg add HKLM\Software\microsoft\windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v 
EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /D 0 /f
echo  0 %errorlevel%
)


Timeout 5
shutdown /r /t 0
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53961305/how-to-get-data-from-a-registry-key-value-via-command-line to *read* a value from the Registry in  batch script, then use that for your IF statement, per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384358/batch-if-elseif-else

Comment: I tried tro modify mine but not work. How to post my modified code for review ??

Comment: @VB88 You can edit the question  https://superuser.com/posts/1716007/edit (links near the bottom of the post)

Comment: I think I already posted my new script. Please how to make it works. Thanks